# I want to merge the rows for a particular values in csv file

Tags: python-3.x, csv, merge

I have a csv file which is structured like that. What I want to achieve is to merge colors .like for product code 1001 there are different colors, i.e BLACK CREAM GRAPHITE, I want one row for 1001 and all colors in one cell ";" (semi colon) separated.I want to do it for all products.

**EDIT**

Requried Output:

> 1001-BLACK-P-OS ,BLACK;CREAM;Graphite
>
> 1002-BLACK-P-OS ,BLACK;CREAM

**Given CSV**

> 1001-BLACK-P-OS ,   BLACK
>
> 1001-CREAM-P-OS  ,  CREAM
>
> 1001-GRAPH-P-OS   , GRAPHITE
>
> 1002-BLACK-P-OS    ,BLACK
>
> 1002-CREAM-P-OS    ,CREAM

I am trying on python but not able to do it.

```
with open('ascolor.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in readCSV:
        serial=row[0]
        d=''
        for r in readCSV:
            if serial is r[0]:
                d=d+r[1]
                d=d+';'
```

Comment: anyone pls comment reason for downvote

Comment: are you really sure you want to store the 3 colors under the key `1001-BLACK-P-OS` ? (not the dv) - `black` is kinda part of the key already

Comment: Yes, Bacause i want to have one entry for each code, i.e 1001 should have one row, When i will use it i will delete the part after four digit code.

Comment: why not store it as `1001,BLACK;CREAM;GRAPHITE` then?

Comment: yes ,but point is how to merge to something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your data file:

```
data = """1001-BLACK-P-OS , BLACK

1001-CREAM-P-OS , CREAM

1001-GRAPH-P-OS , GRAPHITE

1002-BLACK-P-OS ,BLACK

1002-CREAM-P-OS ,CREAM"""

fn = 'ascolor.csv'

with open(fn, "w") as f:
    f.write(data)
```

with that we can start reformatting it:

```
fn = 'ascolor.csv'
import csv    
data = {}
with open(fn) as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in readCSV:
        if row:  # weed out any empty rows - they would cause index errors
            num = row[0].split("-")[0]   # use only the number as key into our dict
            d = data.setdefault(num,[row[0].strip()])  # create the default entry with num as key
                                               # and the old "1001-BLACK-P-OS text as first entry
            if len(d) == 1: # first time we add smth
                d.append([row[1].strip()])     # now add the first color into an inner list
            else:  # this is the second/third color for this key, append to inner list
                d[1].append(row[1].strip()) # this is kindof inefficient string concat

# after that youve got a dictionary of your data:

# print(data)
# {'1001': ['1001-BLACK-P-OS', ['BLACK', 'CREAM', 'GRAPHITE']], 
#  '1002': ['1002-BLACK-P-OS', ['BLACK', 'CREAM']]}


# when writing csv with module, always open file with newline = ""
# else you get silly empty lines inside your file. module csv will do
# all newlines needed. See example at
#    https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer
with open("done.csv","w",newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter=",")
    for k in sorted(data.keys()):
        # this will add the 1001-BLACK-P-OS before it - I dont like that
        # writer.writerow([data[k][0],';'.join(data[k][1])]) 

        # I like this better - its just 1001 and then the colors 
        writer.writerow([k,';'.join(data[k][1])]) 

print("")
with open("done.csv","r") as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Output:

```
1001,BLACK;CREAM;GRAPHITE
1002,BLACK;CREAM
```

or with the commented line:

```
1001-BLACK-P-OS,BLACK;CREAM;GRAPHITE
1002-BLACK-P-OS,BLACK;CREAM
```

HTH

Comment: Awesome, Simply perfect!
I will pray for you for helping me while .
Everyone was downvoting.

Comment: Thank you. Also try to understand what I did so you can try to solve it yourself next time.

Comment: Yes you comments really helping me, You r awesome